# consuming .net core api by xamarin form application

Tags: api, security, .net-core, xamarin.forms, abp

I'm currently working on a Xamarin form that consumes data from the.net core API.
For API side, I use [Abp framework](https://abp.io/).
By using this [reference](https://community.abp.io/articles/abp-framework-api-consumed-by-xamarin.forms-application-rkdfzz66), I can consume data from API.
But in this example, the user needs to login using an administrator credential.
What I need to do is, I just need to consume data from API without login.
Is it correct way if I add [[AllowAnonymous] attribute](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Authorization#advanced-topics) over the API method that I need to access ?

This is the example they show,

```
var accessToken = await _loginService.AuthenticateAsync();
var httpClient = GetHttpClient(accessToken);
```

Is there any example like just using clientId/secrets and without using accessToken?

Comment: from the link you posted: "AllowAnonymous suppresses the authentication. So, GetAsync method is available to everyone including unauthorized users.".  That sounds exactly like what you want.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @Jason, yes, I already tried it and it's ok. What I want to know is the API security. Let say I want to consume this method from mobile, do I still need to configure client Id and secrets ? what're clientId/secrets stand for?

Comment: Well, obviously if you disable authentication then the API "is available to everyone including unauthorized users" as the docs say.  I don't see any mention of clientid/secrets in the docs.

Comment: Reading ABP docs, sounds like it is based on asp.net core authentication. For your goal, I think you first manually create on your server a user and password that your app will use to make requests. You send that user+password as if that user were logging in. [Here is an ASP.NET Core tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/21/aspnet-core-3-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) that uses this technique - see mention of json username password in request body. I don’t know how you adapt that to ABP.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do is, I just need to consume data from API without login.

This refers to **Server-to-Server** authentication; backend making request to an other backend without user interaction.

The authentication flow you are looking for, is named [Client Credentials Flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4).

It boils down to:

- Add your api (abp app) as an **api resource** and **api scope** at authentication server.
- Add your ui app (xamarin app) as a **client** at authentication server.
- Declare a **client secret** for your xamarin app at authentication server.
- Make an access_token request from xamarin app to **authentication server** with the **api scope** and **client secret** *that you have already created above*.

Its implementation can be varied on **authentication server provider** (namely your _loginService). It can be Identityserver4, Microsoft, Google etc etc.

If you are using ABP application backend (as authentication server), it handles most of the automated stuff in the background. You can check [abp synchronous communication between microservices docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/startup-templates/microservice/synchronous-interservice-communication) that has explanation about how client credentials is used between microservices.